# How to select one or more characters that is not intersect with a particular word

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple question. 
I want to select one or more characters(starting and ending phrase) that is not intersect with a particular word.

Eg : I want select 1234, efghijabcklmn from the next text.

```
String now   = "abcd";
String next  = "1234abcdefghijabcklmn";
```

I tried ^abcd, ^(abcd), [^a][^b][^c][^d] nothing works. I know this can be done by splitting and tokenizing. but i want it through regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know this can be done by splitting and tokenizing. but i want it
>   through regex.

Well, [`String#split(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a `regex` as parameter only. So, why not use it, given that this problem is an ideal candidate of *splitting*.

```java
String now = "abcd";
String next = "1234abcdefghijabcklmn";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(next.split(Pattern.quote(now))));
```

Comment: 100% agreed! it can be used to get the job done. But I want to learn how to write a regex expression to do it. My purpose is not to get the result of splitting it. But I wanna learn how to write it in regex. if we can select a matching word in regex. There must be the reverse as well right?

Comment: @NamalFernando. No, there is no way to use regex like this. You canno skip a sequence of characters. The best you can achieve is using pattern like: `(.*?)abcd(.*)` and get the group 1 and group 2 back.

Answer (score 2):

just split the abcd...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("1234abcdefghijabcklmn".split("abcd")));
```

Comment: 100% agreed! it can be used to get the job done. But I want to learn how to write a regex expression to do it. My purpose is not to get the result of splitting it. But I wanna learn how to write it in regex. if we can select a matching word in regex. There must be the reverse as well right?