# How to use a variable within pattern to replaceAll except?

Tags: java, regex, string

How would I replace all that is not stored in the variable guess in the current `Pattern` with a "-"? The guess will change with different method calls. I want to replace anything that is not the char guess(in this case => 'e') with a "-".

```
String word = "ally";
char guess = 'e';
String currentPattern = word.replaceAll("[^guess]", "-");
```

Obviously, this does not work.

Comment: That is a Java question. Not related to Regex at all :)

Comment: Sorry, I am new on here:)

Comment: You must add guess as a variable as jlordo says. Anyway I had a similar question some time back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932510/how-to-select-one-or-more-characters-that-is-not-intersect-with-a-particular-wor

Comment: replaceAll can get a regexp in it's arguments... so it's a regexp related question

Comment: @ben75: It might be related to regex, but the question basically is _how do I insert variable content into a string_, which is basic java, nothing else.

Comment: @jlodo it's more related to "how inserting a variable in regexp pattern ?" (see your own answer to note that the fact it's a replacement in a regexp pattern is important ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it. Use String concatenation:

```
String currentPattern = word.replaceAll("[^" + guess + "]", "-");
```

This approach only works if you don't have regex metacharacters within `guess`, which need to be escaped within character classes. Otherwise a `PatternSyntaxException` will be thrown.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604879/java-regex-illegal-escape-character-in-character-class) shows that in your case, where you only add a `char` to your character class, a `PatternSyntaxException` won't happen even if you don't escape anything.

Comment: But this will replace the word when the characters are interchanged as well right? I mean if the word = "abcdfeghijklmnop" and out put will be same for when the guess = "ghij" and guess = "jihg".

Comment: @NamalFernando: `guess` is a `char`, so it is always only 1 character.

Comment: Ooops! missed it. My Bad! :)

Comment: Thank you! In this case, I will never have regex metacharacters within guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just use `+` concatenation operator to concatenate guess with the regex part.

```
            String word = "ally";
        char guess = 'e';
        String currentPattern = word.replaceAll("[^"+guess+"]", "-");
        System.out.println(currentPattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the variable explicitly in the regex string:

```
String word = "alely";
char guess = 'e';
System.out.println(word.replaceAll(String.format("[^%s]", guess), "-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a method?

```
public String replaceAllExcept( String input, char pattern ) {
    return input.replaceAll( "[^" + pattern + "]", "-" );
}

System.out.println( replaceAllExcept( "ally", 'e' );
System.out.println( replaceAllExcept( "tree", 'e' );
```